# Integrated JavaScript Checker & Minifier/Obfusicator?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, minify, lint, error-checking

I know there are JavaScript obfusicators/minifiers and checkers (like Lint).  But is there one that is integrated and has project support?

Basically, I have a bunch of JavaScript files that are part of a project, and I'd love to be able to have a tool automatically check all of them for various errors (like a compiler would) and produce obfusicated/minified code for each as output.

What integrated tools have you used that you can recommend (I'm not asking for the best, just something you used personally and can recommend). If there is no tool that fulfills all the above, what about tools that do the individual parts (like checking) -- again, things you have used and can recommend.

Comment: What platform are you interested in?

Comment: The platform is Windows.